# WriteProcessMemory from Ctypes failing with code 0 or 998

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

Intent: Execute shellcode (pop calculator) from python. Arch 64 bit, Python 3
Tried: Argtypes, right access permissions, tried every ctypes way there is on the internet.
Error: Code 0 or 998 on WriteProcessMemory.
How can I write to process memory so I can go with createRemoteThread later?

Code:

```
    shellcode = bytearray("\x89\xe5\x83\...", "utf-8").hex()

# buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(shellcode)

PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x2
PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x8
PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x20
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x10
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x400

REQUIRED_RIGHTS_TO_INJECT = PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION \
                            | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ

PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40

MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000
MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000

START_RUNNING = 0x0


kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
process_id = os.getpid()
shellcode_length = len(shellcode)

process_handle = kernel32.OpenProcess(REQUIRED_RIGHTS_TO_INJECT, False, process_id)
if process_handle != 0:
    print("Process Handle: ", process_handle)
else:
    print("Error from open: ", get_last_error())

memory_allocation_variable = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(process_handle, None, shellcode_length+1024, MEM_COMMIT,
                                                              PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
if memory_allocation_variable is None:
    print("Fetching base address failed: ", get_last_error())
else:
    print("Base Address: ", hex(memory_allocation_variable))


WriteProcessMemory = kernel32.WriteProcessMemory
WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID, wintypes.LPCVOID, ctypes.c_size_t,
                               ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
WriteProcessMemory.restypes = wintypes.BOOL

wr = kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(process_handle, memory_allocation_variable, shellcode, shellcode_length, None)
if wr == 0:
    print("Write process failed: ", get_last_error())
else:
    print("Write process memory success")
```

OUTPUT:
Process Handle:  488
Base Address:  0x4d970000
Write process failed:  998

Comment: Make sure to set `.argtypes` and `.restype` for **all** the functions you are using in `kernel32`.  The default return type is `int` (typically 32-bit) for example, but `VirtualAllocEx` returns `LPVOID` (often 64-bit depending on OS) so the return value is truncated and probably the cause of error 998 (Invalid access to memory location.).  `OpenProcess` returns a HANDLE which is 64-bit on 64-bit OS as well.  `shellcode` should be simple `bytes` as well` (`shellcode = b'\x89\xe5\x83\...')` not encoded and hex-ified.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advice. Found the argtypes and security descriptors. Introduced them to code, and now I am getting the success return codes even with CreateRemoteThread. But at the end, Calculator is not popping up, and the python is returning a 0xC0000005 error at the end. Any advice on that? I am very close.

Comment: Output:
Process Handle:  580
Base Address:  0x1734d9b0000
Write process memory success. Return Code:  1
Process initiation expected! Return Code:  600

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 0):

Setting Argtypes and Restypes to every function worked.
Example:

```
OpenProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess
OpenProcess.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
OpenProcess.argtypes = (wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.DWORD)

VirtualAllocEx = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx
VirtualAllocEx.restype = wintypes.LPVOID
VirtualAllocEx.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID, 
ctypes.c_size_t, wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.DWORD)

WriteProcessMemory = kernel32.WriteProcessMemory
WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID, 
wintypes.LPCVOID, ctypes.c_size_t,
                               ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
WriteProcessMemory.restypes = wintypes.BOOL

CreateRemoteThread = kernel32.CreateRemoteThread
CreateRemoteThread.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
CreateRemoteThread.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, 
ctypes.c_size_t, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, wintypes.LPVOID, wintypes.DWORD, 
ctypes.c_ulong)
```

Thanks to Mark Tolonen.